# Is There anyway of making a @property variable compulsory ...?

Tags: objective-c, sdk

I am making an SDK and i want something like **@required** for a variable. Something like delegate method with the @required annoation which make that method to conform mandatory. How can i achieve this thing in objective-c ..?

Comment: have you tried using `nonnil` property attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You may add a property declaration to a protocol, just as you would with any other method. As always with protocols, members are required by default.

If the required property is `readwrite` (the default), then conforming classes must implement both the getter and the setter. They may do so manually or with compiler-provided implementations, as your needs dictate. Similarly, if the required property is `readonly`, only the getter must be implemented, though of course you may implement the setter as well.

```
@protocol SerialNumbered <NSObject>

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *serialNumber;

@end
```

Comment: I have to conform to the protocol in the project which i have to use this varibale..? i am a swift developer with a little bit knowledge of Obj-c

Comment: I don't really understand your (comment's) question. _Classes_ conform to _protocols_. To require that an object implementing a delegate _protocol_ has a certain property, include the property in the delegate protocol as required.